# the hello world program gets crashes when i run in my android device

Tags: android

I get this error when i run the program without any change in eclipse:

This is the code part:

```
 package com.exampl.notes;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This is all the error and warnings in LogCat when i run in my android device, these are the ones shown in red and orange color:

```html
06-28 20:26:12.968: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:13.028: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:13.898: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:13.948: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:14.008: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:14.078: E/qcom_sensors_hal(749): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-28 20:26:34.518: W/dalvikvm(14995): JNI WARNING: NewStringUTF input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xff
06-28 20:26:34.518: W/dalvikvm(14995):              string: 'en_Latn_US_?_US'
06-28 20:26:34.518: W/dalvikvm(14995):              in Llibcore/icu/ICU;.addLikelySubtags:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (NewStringUTF)
06-28 20:26:34.528: E/dalvikvm(14995): VM aborting
06-28 20:26:34.528: A/libc(14995): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00003a93 (code=-6), thread 14995 (om.exampl.notes)
06-28 20:26:34.848: W/ActivityManager(749):   Force finishing activity com.exampl.notes/.MainActivity
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749): Exception thrown during pause
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749): android.os.DeadObjectException
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:765)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2497)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2374)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2068)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9736)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9629)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10280)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9825)
06-28 20:26:34.948: W/ActivityManager(749):  at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
06-28 20:26:44.538: W/EventLoggerService(3926): Unable to send logs Error code: 262160 | The connection was not attempted due to lack of network connectivity.
```

the Layout file is over here:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.exampl.notes.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the android manifest.xml is here

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exampl.notes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please paste the complete log associated with the error

Comment: i need 10 reputation to post the picture so could you like my question so that i can post the picture

Comment: You dont have to paste the picture of it..you have to copy paste the logs

Comment: where can i find the logs in eclipse??

Comment: GO to Window->Show View->Other…->Android->LogCat. After that open the app again and the error will come up in red mostly

Comment: sir i have just edited my question

Comment: More logs are required. Paste the lines after VM abortin

Comment: this is the errors and warns i get while run the program in android app

Comment: Your code seems fine. Based on the logs its very hard to find the problem as the logs dont seem to mention the problem which it usually does

Comment: i have tried to run using android studio but also it crashes in my android device

Comment: Can you update the question with the layout file(activity_main) and the manifest too.

Comment: Try adding TextView to java